# How do I include PSTricks pictures in a LaTeX document?

Tags: pstricks

I use LaTeX regularly, and several times I have included `.eps` images.  I am learning how to use PSTricks.  I have used it to create `.ps` and `.pdf` files with images.  There is plenty of free information on the web, but I haven't seen the answer to this question: how do you include the pictures that PSTricks produces in your LaTeX file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have image files (EPS or PDF) you can include them with the `graphicx` package and `\includegraphics{<filename>}`. `latex` needs an EPS and `pdflatex` a PDF file. If you put both in your folder and omit the suffix in the including macro the package decied which file to use automatically.

If you want to include the PSTricks code directly you may use the `{pspicture}`environment.

Answer (score 11):

Say your PSTricks figure file looks like this:

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2.4)(7.72,2.4)
\psframe[linewidth=0.04,dimen=outer](7.72,2.4)(0.0,-2.4)
\end{pspicture}
```

saved by the name `picture_file.tex` in the same folder as your main latex file.

In your latex main file, saved by the name `main_file.tex`, add

```
\usepackage{pstricks}    %for embedding pspicture.
\usepackage{graphicx}    %for figure environment.
```

in the preamble. (You can add additional things also as your needs.)

Now, the `picture_file.tex` can be included in the `main_file.tex` as:

```
%=========================
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering{
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{picture_file.tex}}}
\caption{your caption} \label{fig:figureone}
\end{figure}
%===========================
```

Only the `main_file.tex` needs be compiled.

**Note:-**

1. If you use different fonts other than default ones, the fonts in figures will blend perfectly with the rest of the document by this method.
2. Make sure the `\documentclass[...]{...}` does not have `minimal` or `letter` as the type, in which case, the `figure` environment would not be recognized.

Comment: Note 3. Compile your `main_file.tex` using Xelatex.

Answer (score 8):

If you write each PSTricks diagram in a separate TeX input file and compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (much faster) or `xelatex` (slower) to obtain a PDF output, you might need the PDF output without white spaces around it.

To obtain the tight PDF output, use the following template for each diagram you want to make.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3,-3)(3,3)
% your drawing code goes here!
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It will be better if you put all your TeX input files for creating diagrams in a special folder outside other projects you have. This method will make your diagrams consumable to many projects easily. My directory structures look like below.

[image]

All my TeX input file for creating diagrams are placed in `Diagrams`. The PDF outputs associated with the input files are also in `Diagrams` for sure.

Another project, namely `ProjectA`, might use the diagrams you have made before.
For  example, let `Main.tex` be the input file in `ProjectA` folder. You can import the diagrams easily as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../Diagrams/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{Template}
\caption{This is my PSTricks template.}
\label{fig:Template}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The important points are:

- Load `graphicx` and set the graphics path. Adjust the scale to meet your preference.
- Compile it with `pdflatex` or `xelatex`. You cannot use `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` unless you have `EPS` equivalent for each PDF output.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I ended up using \documentclass[12pt]{standalone} in the file where the picture was drawn.  It worked fine.

Comment: @user20520: `standalone` internally uses `preview` package.

Comment: @bogus: I updated the template in my answer, now it uses `standalone` class you prefer.