# want pdf picture to be smaller than one page

Tags: pdf, margins, pstricks, crop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I crop included PDF documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25806/how-can-i-crop-included-pdf-documents)

I created a `pdf` file using `PSTricks`.  It appears to occupy an entire page.  When I included it in my LaTeX file using `\includegraphics`, the image occupies an entire page and the figure number is missing.

How can I create a `.pdf` file smaller than one page and include it in my LaTeX file?

Comment: the `\includegraphics` command can be used as `\includegraphics[width=<width>]`. You won't get a 'Figure number', unless you add `\caption{<Caption stuff>}`. Alternatively, why not create the graphic inside the actual document- you can use `\psset{unit=<something>}` to scale the image

Comment: Related questions: [How can I crop included PDF documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25806/3323), [Minimize automatically the page size of the PDF outputs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32773/3323)

Comment: You might need [How to manage your PSTricks diagrams and using them in many document projects.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48924/9467)